# Как настроить точку входа в сервлет?

Tags: java-ee, tomcat, servlet

Стоит TomCat 9 пишу в последней IntelliJ IDEA написал пару сервлетов все работает но не так как нужно!
В файле web.xml прописал велком файл

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Есть сервлет тоже прописан в web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>WarmStar</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>warmStar.WarmStar</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WarmStar</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/warmStar</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

При запуске index.jsp отрабатывает и url в браузере такой - localhost:8085
мне нужно что бы при первом запуске url был такой- localhost:8085/warmStar 
что бы это сходу было.
То есть получается что бы сходу начал работать сервлет который отобразил мне вот это страницу index.jsp
Я пробовал в сервлет маппинг изменять урл-паттерн на пустой или просто слэш ставить, сервлет отрабатывает запускает index.jsp, но путь урл в браузере остается вот таким localhost:8085
В дуГете в сервлете делаю форвард на index.jsp
И да стоит сказать что это мое первое приложение, извеняюсь если глупости написал.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в `index.jsp` такую строчку: `<jsp:forward page="warmStar"/>`. Ещё можете поменять параметр `Server->Open Browser` в настройках `Tomcat` на `localhost:8085/warmStar`

Comment: Ошибка вылетает

Comment: Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [9]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [9]

6:   To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
7: --%>
8: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
9: <jsp:forward page="warmStar"/>
10: <html>
11:   <head>
12:

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, нужно чтобы при переходе на url сервлета открывался index.jsp. Если у вас index.jsp лежит по умолчанию в корне webapp, то укажите его без слеша:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```